# Copy value from one row to another row in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
id   product   amount
1    A         6
1    A         8
1    A         
1    B         1
1    B         
2    C         2
2    C       
2    C         4
2    C    
2    C
```

and I need to make it like this:

```
id   product   amount
1    A         6
1    A         8
1    A         8
1    B         1
1    B         1
2    C         2
2    C         2
2    C         4
2    C         4
2    C         4
```

Copy amount by previous non-missing value.

I tried to use `lag()` function. however, aggregation function `lag()` is not allowed in UPDATE.

```
update tableA set amount = lag(amount);
```

What can I do using PostgreSQL?

Comment: What defines here "previous"  row ?

Comment: `order by id,product,random()` or ctid I believe

Comment: yes, similar to lag() function. however i can't use aggregation function lag() in update ...

Comment: you can use lag() with CTE - the problem is absence of ordering column

Comment: what is CTE? I think I can't order by id and product, because id=2,product=C correspond two values: 2 and 4

Comment: You have three (2, C, NULL). One will get the `amount = 2`, the other two will get `amount = 4`. This is only achievable by using `ROW_NUMBER`. It's dangerous to rely on the **PHYSICAL** order of the rows **WITHOUT EXPLICIT ORDERING**, which in your case is not possible, because you have duplicates. Is it acceptable to use the same amount per group `(id, product)`? In other words, can all `(2, C, NULL)` get the same `amount = 4` for example and become `(2, C, 4)`? They could also all become `(2, C, 2)`, for example. Is that okay? Should all `(2, C, zzz)` behave the same and have the same zzz?

Comment: @TingZhang added an answer. Please mark it correct, if it is correct. Also please upvote, if it helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `SELECT` what you want to `UPDATE`, but there is no (easy) way to actually do the `UPDATE`, because the table fox does not have a primary key (yet).

```
CREATE TABLE fox (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    product text NOT NULL,
    amount integer
);
```

To populate the fox with some data.

```
INSERT INTO fox VALUES 
(1, 'A', 6),
(1, 'A', 8),
(1, 'A', NULL),
(1, 'B', 1),
(1, 'B', NULL),
(2, 'C', 2),
(2, 'C', NULL),
(2, 'C', 4),
(2, 'C', NULL),
(2, 'C', NULL), 
(3, 'What does the fox say?', 5);
```

The query.

```
WITH ranks (rank, id, product, amount) AS (  
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (), id, product, amount FROM foo  
)  
SELECT r.id, r.product,  
  (SELECT amount FROM ranks  
    WHERE id = r.id AND product = r.product  
      AND rank < r.rank AND amount IS NOT NULL  
    ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 1  
  )  
FROM ranks r WHERE r.amount IS NULL ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Yields the rows which previously had a `NULL` and now have the appropriate `amount`.

```
 id | product | amount 
----+---------+--------
  1 | A       |      8
  1 | B       |      1
  2 | C       |      2
  2 | C       |      4
  2 | C       |      4
```

But you cannot use this data to update, because rows are still not uniquely identified by `(id, product)` - which means you cannot write a `WHERE` condition identifying your rows uniquely. How would the `WHERE` clause know whether to change the amount to 2 or 4 in the `UPDATE`? The multiple rows with `(id, product) = (2, 'C')` are indistinguishable in the `WHERE` of the `UPDATE`.

Let's give the fox a primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE fox ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS pkey serial ;  
ALTER TABLE fox ADD PRIMARY KEY (pkey) ;
```

Now we can identify the rows by the  `PRIMARY KEY pkey`.

```
WITH nulls AS ( 
  SELECT pkey, id, product  
  FROM fox  
  WHERE amount IS NULL 
) 
SELECT pkey,  
  id, product,  -- you can leave these out in your UPDATE: pkey is UNIQUE
  (SELECT amount FROM fox  
   WHERE id = n.id AND product = n.product  
     AND n.pkey > pkey AND amount IS NOT NULL  
   ORDER BY pkey DESC LIMIT 1)  
FROM nulls n ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

to display the changes to be made

```
 pkey | id | product | amount 
------+----+---------+--------
    3 |  1 | A       |      8
    5 |  1 | B       |      1
    7 |  2 | C       |      2
    9 |  2 | C       |      4
   10 |  2 | C       |      4
```

And we can use `pkey` in the `UPDATE`.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE ;

WITH nulls AS ( 
      SELECT pkey, id, product  
      FROM fox  
      WHERE amount IS NULL 
    ), changes AS ( 
    SELECT pkey,  
      (SELECT amount FROM fox  
       WHERE id = n.id AND product = n.product  
         AND n.pkey > pkey AND amount IS NOT NULL  
       ORDER BY pkey DESC LIMIT 1)  
    FROM nulls n 
) UPDATE fox f SET amount = c.amount FROM changes c WHERE f.pkey = c.pkey ;
```

Check the result is okay:

```
SELECT * FROM fox ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

And accept using `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` accordingly.

**Alternative to adding a PRIMARY KEY**

Every table should always have a primary key. 
If you insist not to have one, then you could also compute the rows with their then-not-NULL amount and **instead of `UPDATE`ing** them, you could **`INSERT` them** into your table and **then `DELETE FROM fox WHERE amount IS NULL`** remove the rows which had no amount. This way you get around adding a primary key, which is unique. Of course the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are packaged into a `TRANSACTION` such as not to interfere with other Transactions running concurrently. For example another Transaction adding rows with `NULL` amount AFTER you have calculated the data to be `INSERT`ed using `SELECT` and before you `DELETE` all `NULL amount`s. You'd miss the concurrently added row with `NULL amount` in this case (data loss due to concurrency; think ACID).
But a missing primary key will probably bite you later on, anyway.

Comment: Hi @flutter. You seem to be giving some really great answers and are having a run of bad luck - you seem to be choosing questions posted by some rather unhelpful posters. Sympathies! I normally say that new users can be a risk in this regard, but I don't want to end up advocating that they are not helped at all - just be aware that a lot of effort is not always appreciated in these cases. Also, it is worth analysing the question to see if any effort was made - there was zero here, which is another red flag.

Comment: However, you should know that your answers will be very helpful to future users, and hopefully that is where you will get your appreciation (both in terms of votes and positive comments).

Comment: @flutter Hi, at first, I need to thanks for your patient explanation. I left for a few days and just check this post. I am testing your solution, I got different results before adding primary key. The amount was 6 1 4 4 4 for the first time, null 2 2 null null for the second time, and many different results each time I ran. Furthermore, when adding pkey by "ALTER TABLE fox ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS pkey serial;", I got an error: "Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "NOT";". I am not able to adapt the code right now. In this condition, could you help me again? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can inspect your table schema using `\dt table` in Postgres. If the column `pkey` does not yet exist, then you can leave out the `IF NOT EXISTS` part. This part was added in a later version of Postgres and might not be available in your version. But it's a minor thing. If you leave it out and the column already exists, then i expect an error to be produced. Nothing should be broken by trying this `ALTER TABLE fox ADD COLUMN ...` .

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what defines "previous rows" all is a guess. But you can use a [anonymous block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) to do what your want, just make your changes:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_lag AS
    SELECT column1 AS id, column2 AS product, column3 AS amount FROM (
        VALUES (1, 'A', 6), 
        (1, 'A', 8),
        (1, 'A', NULL),
        (1, 'B', 1),
        (1, 'B', NULL),
        (2, 'C', 2),
        (2, 'C', NULL),
        (2, 'C', 4),
        (2, 'C', NULL),
        (2, 'C', NULL)) AS tmp;

DO $$
BEGIN
    --Loop until update all null amounts
    --Why we need this? It's because PostgreSQL don't supports IGNORE NULLS clause on lag()
    LOOP
        WITH tmp AS (
            SELECT ctid, lag(amount) OVER() AS last_amount FROM test_lag ORDER BY id, product -- You MUST change this ORDER to right columns (What's previous row?)
        )
        UPDATE test_lag SET amount = tmp.last_amount FROM tmp WHERE test_lag.ctid = tmp.ctid AND amount IS NULL;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;    
    END LOOP;

END $$;

SELECT * FROM test_lag ORDER BY id, product, amount;
```

Comment: The `LAG()` function will only fill `NULL` with values right next to each other. There are multiple `NULL` values. Therefore your query needs to be run `n` times to fill a sequence of one value `x` followed by `n` `NULL` values. Other queries succeed in one go. But it's an interesting solution. Thank you for teaching me that.

Comment: I can read your code, but I can't implement the test on my system. I am not practiced of sql, so I am not able to tell and adapt the code. There could be some difference between our software. I am still very appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TingZhang No problem. Best regards.